# String going crazy if I don't give it a little extra room. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Tags: c++, c, string, variables

First, I'd like to say that I'm new to C / C++, I'm originally a PHP developer so I am bred to abuse variables any way I like 'em.

C is a strict country, compilers don't like me here very much, I am used to breaking the rules to get things done.

Anyway, this is my simple piece of code:

```
char IP[15] = "192.168.2.1";
char separator[2] = "||";   

puts( separator );
```

Output:

```
||192.168.2.1
```

But if I change the definition of `separator` to:

```
char separator[3] = "||";
```

I get the desired output:

```
||
```

So why did I need to give the man extra space, so he doesn't sleep with the man before him?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's because you get a not null-terminated string when `separator` length is forced to 2.

Always remember to allocate an extra character for the null terminator. For a string of length `N` you need `N+1` characters.

Once you violate this requirement any code that expects null-terminated strings (`puts()` function included) will run into undefined behavior.

Your best bet is to not force any specific length:

```
char separator[] = "||";
```

will allocate an array of exactly the right size.

Comment: Bugger! Does that mean I have to go back and increment all my variable lengths?

Comment: Referring to some character array as a "not null-terminated string" is the same as referring to some primate as "not human person" :)

Comment: Can anyone fix this for vim please real quick: `:%s/\[\d\]\+/\=submatch(0)+1/g`

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Hmm.. You don't allocate a null-terminator. Do you have to go back and fix it? Yes, you have.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: why do you need to increment all variable lengths?? If the size of all character arrays are known a priori, then you can use the scheme above, char separator[], or leave the size blank (but initialize the char array there itself) and let the compiler figure the length out for itself.

Comment: Ok, so everyone has explained the null character, and that's cool. It makes perfect sense! But why was seperator chilling with IP? My assumption would be that memory is first allocated to seperator and then to IP. So when I reference to seperator, it doesn't have a null character and doesn't outputting itself until a null character is encountered, correct?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Yes, that's the most reasonable explanation, but in general such situations are called undefined behavior which means "anything (usually bad) can happen, don't analyze that too long".

Comment: @Sriram: I just like to defining the lengths myself. I makes me feel like a good citizen. I don't really understand the pro / cons of it, to be honest with you. But nonetheless, I've learned something new today.

Comment: Actually, defining the lengths yourself makes you a bad citizen, because you're likely to make a mistake, where the compiler will not.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa you must understand the pros and cons now, right? :)

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Because you were reading memory too far and it should have thrown an access violation. `puts()` is notorious for this.

Comment: @Code Monkey: why ? undefined behavior is by essence undefined. It *could* have played Beethoven 9th and still conform.

Comment: @pmg what about pascal strings? Rather than a null terminator, they are prefixed with their length. ASCIIZ strings are one possible string format. It's just default, because it was easy on the PDP-11.

Comment: @Dave: in C, strings as used in `<string.h>` are character arrays with a zero byte. Anything else is not a string in the C sense. It was in this context I said what I said. (For all I care a [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) can be called a string in other contexts)

Answer (score 22):

Strings in C are NUL-terminated. This means that a string of two characters requires three bytes (two for the characters and the third for the zero byte that denotes the end of the string).

In your example it is possible to omit the size of the array and the compiler will allocate the correct amount of storage:

```
char IP[] = "192.168.2.1";
char separator[] = "||";
```

Lastly, if you are coding in C++ rather than C, you're better off using `std::string`.

Comment: Related question, are there any downsides of letting the compiler allocate the size of the arrays?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: In your context, no.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Well, sometimes you need to allocate more memory than what is implied by the initializer. In that case you'd need to be explicit.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: and sometimes you actually want a non-NUL terminated character array.... e.g. you might be intending to use the OS `write()` function to output exactly the number of bytes it contains, and don't need it in C-string ASCIIZ format (it might even contain NULs that you want written).  Lazily adding an unnecessary NUL might throw out automatic length calculations using `sizeof` or binding to a reference to an array where the size is a template parameters....

Answer (score 13):

If you're using C++ anyway, I'd recommend using the std::string class instead of C strings - much easier and less error-prone IMHO, especially for people with a scripting language background.

Answer (score 4):

There is a hidden nul character '\0' at the end of each string. You have to leave space for that.

If you do

```
char seperator[] = "||";
```

you will get a string of size 3, not size 2.

Comment: not "is", "should be". You are allowed to make character arrays that don't end with \0. It's just that if you hand them to a function that expects a \0 to mark the end, those functions won't work as you expect them to.

Comment: If it's not nul-terminated, by definition it is not a C string (and thus, will misbehave in functions that expect a C string).  "Is" is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Because in C strings are nul terminated (their end is marked with a 0 byte). If you declare separator to be an array of two characters, and give them both non-zero values, then there is no terminator! Therefore when you `puts` the array pretty much anything could be tacked on the end (whatever happens to sit in memory past the end of the array - in this case, it appears that it's the `IP` array).

**Edit: this following is incorrect.** See comments below.

When you make the array length 3, the extra byte happens to have 0 in it, which terminates the string. However, you probably can't rely on that behavior - if the value is uninitialized it could really contain anything.

Comment: "you probably can't rely on that behavior - if the value is uninitialized it could really contain anything". Yes, but if you use double-quoted string constant as array initializer then you DO initialize the array of proper size with zero-terminated character array. Initializer `"abc"` is equivalent to intializer `{'a','b','c',0}`. So this last statement seems misleading.

Answer (score 2):

In C strings are ended with a special `'\0'` character, so your separator literal `"||"` is actually one character longer.  `puts` function just prints every character until it encounters `'\0'` - in your case one after the IP string.

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings include a (invisible) null byte at the end. You need to account for that null byte.

```
char ip[15] = "1.2.3.4";
```

in the code above, `ip` has enough space for 15 characters. 14 "regular characters" and the null byte. It's too short: should be `char ip[16] = "1.2.3.4";`

```
ip[0] == '1';
ip[1] == '.';
/* ... */
ip[6] == '4';
ip[7] == '\0';
```

Comment: How is that line the problem? ip has space enough for 14 characters + 1 null. In your example, ip would have only 7 characters + 1 null, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Sriram: It's a variable, not a constant, so IP should have room for 15 + 1 characters

Comment: Pardon me, but I dont get it. Why is ip short when we have 15 characters worth of space allocated and we are storing only 8? char ip[15] is more than enough for "1.2.3.4" above, right?

Comment: It will be wrong with a larger IP address: "123.124.125.126" needs 16 characters. It works for the small example, but when, later, you need a larger IP, it will fail --- `strcpy(ip, "123.124.125.126"); /* BOOOM! */`

Comment: yeah. I thought you meant it would fail with the smaller IP address too, and so thought i had missed something. that explanation sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one pointed it out so far: If you declare your variable like this, the strings will be automagically null-terminated, and you don't have to mess around with the array sizes:

```
const char* IP = "192.168.2.1"; 
const char* seperator = "||";
```

Note however, that I assume you don't intend to change these strings.

But as already mentioned, the safe way in C++ would be using the std::string class.

Comment: Would this work with variables as well? `char* IP ="192.168.2.1";` ?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Yes, that's allowed by the language. But in 99% you'll want to make them `const`, otherwise you'll be surprised again. The reason can be another question :P For your purpose ("variable"), you probably want to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: definition `const char* IP = "192.168.2.1";` defines a _variable_ of type pointer to constant character.

Comment: @kizzx2:  Allowed by the language here is a bit too generous.  string literal to char * conversions have been deprecated since '98.

Answer (score 1):

A C "String" always  ends in NULL, but you just do not give it to the string if you write
char separator[2] = "||". And puts expects this \0 at the ned in the first case it writes till it finds a \0 and here you can see where it is found at the end of the IP address. Interesting enoiugh you can even see how the local variables are layed out on the stack.

Comment: It is actually common to regard the character `'\0'` and `NULL` as distinct. There even used to be C compilers where NULL was defined as `(void) 0` in the header files.

Answer (score 1):

The line: `char seperator[2] = "||"`; should get you undefined behaviour since the length of that character array (which includes the null at the end) will be 3.

Also, what compiler have you compiled the above code with? I compiled with g++ and it flagged the above line as an error.

Comment: In C, behaviour is well defined. `seperator` is not a string though.

Comment: @pmg: then is there such a thing as string in c?

Comment: there is not a type (or any other contruct) for `string` in C. Strings are defined as **character arrays which include a null byte**.

Comment: @pmg: OK. Though the context you mentioned was the same as that which I had in mind too.

Answer (score 1):

[String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string) in C\C++ are null terminated, i.e. have a hidden zero at the end.

So your separator string would be:

```
{'|', '|', '\0'} = "||"
```